How to cover with unit test a settimeout in a event listener in angular method?
Using jasmine and karma, I can pass the unit test using fake async and using a real event, but the coverage is not correct, the settimeout call back is ignored.
@Component({
  selector: 'slider',
  templateUrl: './slider.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./slider.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  standalone: true,
  imports: [AgGridModule],
})
export class SliderComponent {
  otherMethod() {}
   
  onSliderReady() {
    window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.otherMethod();
      });
    });
  }
}

The unit test is working as expecting, the tick could be optional (not affecting the assertion).
  describe('onSliderReady', () => {
    it('should call otherMethod', fakeAsync(() => {
      spyOn(component, 'otherMethod')
      window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));

      component.onSliderReady();
      tick(500);

      expect(component.otherMethod).toHaveBeenCalled();
    }));
  });



Do I understand your problem correctly: the test does not go into the otherMethod() via the onSliderReady() method? So the test "onSliderReady" fails?

the unit test is working as expected, the problem is that the pecentage of the file is very low because the settimeout is in red,

Ah you mean the test coverage. Sorry, I overlooked that

Yeah, test coverage, no problem, just looking this is very tricky
